# Why is UIButton not responding to touches?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I've look at many responses and still cannot figure it out. I know the first line is a little weird, but its because it is inheriting from a super class that sets the headerview to search bar

```
searchBar = (UISearchBar *)self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
[[searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -100, self.view.frame.size.width, 100)];
label.text = @"AAAA";
[searchBar addSubview:label];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(aMethod)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, -60, 160.0, 40.0);

searchBar.exclusiveTouch = NO;
searchBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
label.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[searchBar insertSubview:button atIndex:3];
```

Comment: try to set `searchBar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` instead

Comment: I've tried that and it does not work

Comment: Also tried and doesn't work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is your answer :
    searchBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
If you are going to add a subview to a view that has userInteraction disabled then that subview won't receive touches. I haven't looked very good at your code to see if there are other mistakes.

Look at the frames in the first place :

**button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, -60, 160.0, 40.0);**

**UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -100, self.view.frame.size.width, 100);**

The button isn't visible at all , and the label the same , the objects are placed **outside of bounds** and that's why you cannot touch them.

Comment: yeah, they are placed out of bounds. can touches not be sent to something out of bounds? They are still visible because I am displaying the tableview at an offset. Edit: THIS WORKS.

Comment: no, the touches cannot be sent there, it's like you would try to move a image in the right of your screen and only see a corner , you are trying to see what is outside. I've had this asked with an iOS Engineer at WWDC .

Comment: Apparently this can be done if you override a method. Not worth it in this case though. Thanks

Comment: i think you are referring to hitTest. but yeah, not worthed.

Comment: Wow, the subview bounds observation was spot on!!! I have changed the subview's background color to Red and have immediately discovered that the subview (that contains the unresponsive UISwitch) has the height of 0 points (no where to be found.) The UISwitch started to respond to taps as soon as I adjusted the bottom constraint of the subview to match the height of the UISwitch.

Answer (score 10):

userInteractionEnabled set to NO on a parent view will cascade down to all subviews. Thus, your instance of UIButton will appear unresponsive because the searchBar is disabled.

Comment: It still doesn't work even if i delete searchbar.exclusive touch and searchbar.userinteractionenabled